# Convert key value object to json - javascript

Tags: javascript, php, json

Hey All I have this object that I try to convert to json.
I tried

```
reportDropDownsJson2 =  JSON.parse('{"' + reportDropDownsJson.replace(/&/g, '","').replace(/=/g,'":"') + '"}', function(key, value) { return key===""?value:decodeURIComponent(value) });
            reportDropDownsJson['downloadcsv'] = true;
```

and the result is:

```
TypeError: reportDropDownsJson.replace is not a function
```

this is the object (called reportDropDownsJson)  that I try to convert to json

```
ad_type: ""
agency_id[]: ""
auction_type: ""
brand_id[]: ""
campaign: ""
campaign-drop: ""
column_filter[]: (23) ['Timestamp', 'Date', 'Hour', 'Brand', 'Requests', 'Bids', 'Bid %', 'Wins', 'Win %', 'Fill %', 'Imps Pixel', 'Revenue $', 'Cost $', 'eCPM', 'Sales Person', 'AdOPS Person', 'Account Manager Person', 'IVT Provider 1', 'Viewability Provider 1', 'VCR', 'CTR', 'VTR', 'Campaign']
deal_id[]: ""
deal_personnel[]: ""
deal_type[]: ""
device_type: ""
dsp_id[]: ""
edit_saved_report: ""
end_date: "2022-02-16"
frozen_filter[]: "Timestamp"
group_by[]: ""
interval: "hourly"
media_type: ""
office_country[]: "All"
pub_id[]: ""
ssp_id[]: ""
start_date: "2022-02-16"
timezone: "US/Eastern"
_token: "Fixv8PZsW6vsavjysdbVcxDsedqy8tiw7s7vUVBp"
```

Comment: `replace` is a method for string, but not for object.

Comment: OK you have any other suggestion?

Comment: If you want to convert an object to json. You can use `JSON.stringify(object)`

Comment: `JSON.parse()` converts JSON into an actual thing (object/array/whatever)... `JSON.stringify()` generates JSON.

Answer (score 1):

We cant use `replace` on objects.It can be used on strings.If you want to replace the values of object you can loop through object and use replace on single values.

Yoc can try this method to get values of an object:

```
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(reportDropDownsJson)) {
  console.log(`${key}: ${value}`);
}
```

Inside for loop you can use `value.replace()` and do whatever logic

Answer (score 0):

`Replace` cannot be used in objects.

To iterate the keys and values inside an object, you can do this:

```
Object.entries(reportDropDownsJson).forEach(([key, value]) => {
    // Do whatever you need to write out the json with the "key" and "value" pair
});
```